# Rules of Hooks Where is the top level

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following component in React

```
import React from 'react'
import { Row, Col, Form, Input, Button, Card } from 'antd';
import { FormComponentProps } from 'antd/lib/form/Form';
import Particles from 'react-particles-js';
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { RootState } from '../../services/store/rootReducer';
import { UsersActions } from '../../services/store';

interface LoginProps extends FormComponentProps {
    rootState: RootState
}

class Login extends React.Component<LoginProps> {
    state = { email: '', password: ''};

    changeHandler = (e: any, name: any) => {
        var value = e.target.value;
        this.setState({[name]: value})
    }

    loginUser = () => {
        try {
            UsersActions.loginRequestAsync(this.state, (token: any) => {
                console.log(token);
            });
        } catch(exception)
        {
            console.log(exception)
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { t } = useTranslation();
        const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
        return (
            <div>                
                ///blabla
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
    rootState: state
});
const mapDispatchToProps = {}
const createdForm = Form.create()(Login);

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(createdForm);
```

When I add the line

`const { t } = useTranslation();`

The app do not compile with

×

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
>   function component. This could happen for one of the following
>   reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>   fix this problem.

Now, I tried to understand the rule, hooks must be called only on top level of a component in order for react to always load the component the same way. But where is my top level ?

I tried to put outside of render and as a property of the component, I still have the same loading error.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You broke the rules of Hooks, namely: `No Hooks in classes`.

That should really be the trick here. Try to rewrite it to something like the following:

```
function Login(props: LoginProps) {
    const [data, setData] = useState({ email: '', password: '' });
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    const loginUser = () => { /* ... */ };

    render() {
        return <div>
            {/*...*/ }
        </div>
    }

}
```

On the document pages, there is even a page only on Hook Errors/Warnings:  [Invalid Hook Call Warning](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)

In [Breaking the Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#breaking-the-rules-of-hooks) it states:

> - Do not call Hooks in class components.
> - Do not call in event    handlers.
> - Do not call Hooks inside functions passed to useMemo,    useReducer, or useEffect.

Answer (score 1):

Hooks are used in functional components, here you have a class component that's why it's throwing an error here, error is saying it

> Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Hope it helps